# how to stop/prevent PHP from automatically formatting numbers int scientific notations

Tags: php

I want to show the following numbers with php, but output is strange:

```
echo 3333333333333333333333333333333;  // -----------> 3.3333333333333E+30
echo 0.000025;                         // -----------> 2.5E-5
```

I havent asked it to convert. Why it does that? How should I force it to get/set the values exactly as I ask it?  (p.s. I've heard of `sprint_f` or `number_format` functions, but I don't like them, because i have to know the formatting and length in advance.)

What is more, when I try to save large numbers in Database, there is saved a number: `2147483647` (i found that was the max. integer value). I changed the column type from `int` to `varchar(100)` but still same truncation happens.

Comment: Show your code of how you're creating the value, how you're passing it into the database, and your table schema.

Comment: What datatypes are you using?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: Technically speaking it's not converting it. For example `2.0E+2` is another way of writing 200. If you want the numbers to look nice when you're reading them then use a number formatter.

Comment: Show us the code. That should not be happening

Comment: `3333333333333333333333333333333` is larger than the maximum integer PHP can hold. What you're getting back is a floating point number which is less accurate than what you give it. What @mwweb suggests can help but also keep in mind that you need to store those numbers as text fields in a database as well. What do you need to do with those numbers?

Comment: `var_dump(bcmul('3333333333333333333333333333333', '1', 99));` 99 is the scale

Comment: @yes,  i wanted to store 20 digit numbers as numbers. However, I will try to save as text.

Comment: @mwweb thanks, please post your comment as answer, i will upvote.  p.s. I have posted the answer what solved the problem!

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, please post your comment as answer, i will upvote.  p.s. I have posted the answer what solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Look at your precision setting in php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

It's the setting that says how PHP will output numbers

Answer (score 1):

When you are using such extreme numbers (both negative or positive) the accuracy of the number system in php comes in to play.

Floating point is not accurate for numbers like that, I would suggest using one of the ones listed here

http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php
bc is designed for decimals

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will answer my own topic.

1) The first problem is that PHP truncates LARGE and smallest values... However, I solved that casting values to strings (with double quotes).

2) The second problem was  a bit strange... 
When I first created that MySQL, I made that column as `INT(11)` and then changed column to `Varchar(100)` (exactly as all my other columns were `Varchar(100)` and they could save that value well).

However, that column was truncating values again. Then I **recreated the table, but  changed the COLUMN name** and then IT WORKED WELL! I think, MySQL cached the column type (or surely something like that happened) !

Comment: You are welcome to accept your own answer if you prefer it over the others.